# Image ratio shows not properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-glide

Into this adapter, I build dynamically the imageview size into the viewholder constructor:

```
ContentViewHolder(View view, Context context) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

            // Set image width + height
            mImageView.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(UIUtils.getScreenWidth() / 4f);
            mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = Math.round(
                    mImageView.getLayoutParams().width / Defines.FORM_LIST_FORMAT);
        }
```

To show images, I use **Glide** (with crossfade effect; I tried without and the result is the same...).

And the result is not good: the first images have a bad image displaying...

Could you give some ways to fix it please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in your XML layout, or `mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)` if you want to do it programmatically.

Comment: It's already done this scale type and there is no effect on this problem.

Comment: @anthony then you need to share more code, including your XML